# Handle multiple inputs in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm building a farm management application with Laravel and Vue using Inertia

I have the following tables

```
products (id, name, ...)
nutrients (id, name, ...)
nutrient_product (nutrient_id, product_id, ratio, ...)
```

In the Produtcs/Create.vue component I'm generating multiple html inputs using v-for directive like so

```
<div v-for="nutrient in nutrients" :key="nutrient.id">
     <Input v-model="ratio" type="text" />
</div>
```

The main purpose here is to store the value of `ratio` for each generated nutrient in the `nutrient_product` table

I tried to store the `ration` value for each input in an array but negative. Not sure how to handle this

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad I can help you.

Please try with the below code:

```
<div v-for="nutrient in nutrients" :key="nutrient.id">
     <Input v-model="ratio[nutrient.id]" type="text" />
</div>
```

You will get easily all inputs values in array like below

```
ratio[{
   1: 'Lorem ipsum',
   2: 'Test Value',
   nutrientID: nutrientValue 
}]
```

Thanks!